# Using scanner.next() outside loop yields weird results

Tags: java, loops

Recently a friend of mine showed me her code seeking my advice on why it wouldn't work. Her original code was this:

```
public static void printStem(String word) ...

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the words: "); 
  String word = keyboard.next(); 
  printStem(word);

  while (keyboard.hasNext())
  {
    printStem(word);
    word = keybord.next();
  }
}
```

This will yield really *weird* results. It will ask the user twice, then executes `printStem` twice (which might be expected), and after that goes ahead and always prints *only* the first entered corpus (word).

Eventually I figured out that it would work as expected when removing the `keyboard.next()` from outside the loop like so

```
public static void printStem(String word) ...

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the words: "); 

  while (keyboard.hasNext())
  {
    String word = keybord.next();
    printStem(word);
  }
}
```

When asked why this would be I had no plausible explanation, as this should behave identical. My best guess is that something must be smelly with `hasNext()` but I couldn't figure out why exactly. So. What is going on here? Any explanation is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @Michael I corrected the mentioned issues. However printStem does really only output stuff via System.out.println so it's not much worth mentioning here.

Comment: It is [worth mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I should be able to copy and paste your code in my IDE to work out problem and not have to mess around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some explanation about hasNext():

```
Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. 
This method may block while waiting for input to scan. 
The scanner does not advance past any input.
```

In your first piece of code

> 1. you scan for a word: `String word = keyboard.next();`
> 2. You print it: `printStem(word);`
> 3. You enter into a while loop which waits until you give some input: `keyboard.hasNext()`
> 4. In step 3 you take the input but never store it in String word and you print it. Naturally previous value of word will be printed.
> 5. Then you do a next read by next().

Explanation for next():

`Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.`

Hence you get a weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> This will yield really weird results

Yeah, because the logic is wrong.

You get the input

```
String word = keyboard.next();
```

print it

```
printStem(word);
```

then print it again, and ask for another word:

```
while (keyboard.hasNext())
{
    printStem(word);
    word = keybord.next();
}
```

So every time you loop you print the word they entered *last* time, rather than the word they entered *this* time. You just need to swap the two lines in the while-loop, which then makes the `keyboard.next()` and `printStem(word)` outside of the loop body redundant.

> as this should behave identical

No it shouldn't. You reversed the order of operations in the while-loop body.